# how to replace bar chart after selecting option value using morris-conf.js?

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have created bar chart by retrieving values from database .And used Morris-conf.js.First time when i select value from options i get bar chart properly.

But second time when i select value from option the old bar chart getting down.

my js code is here

```
  Morris.Bar({

                            element: 'hero-bar',

                            data:playdata,
                            xkey: 'playedOn',
                            ykeys: ['playCount'],
                            labels: ['Count'],
                            barRatio: 0.4,
                            xLabelAngle:0,
                            hideHover: 'auto',
                            barColors: ['#ac92ec']
                          });
```

please help me

Thanks

Comment: i am unable to add images

Comment: Can you create a fiddle for the problem

Comment: here is fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/friends/Qp3x5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in the fiddle was that it was not emptying the div before rerendering the plugin. So it was appearing multiple times. Please find the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qp3x5/1/)

Code snippet used:

```
$('#hero-bar').empty();
```